# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - WSO2 API Manager 1.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I get following error when running WSO2 API Manager 1.6 on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open wso2server.sh

```
vim /<product_home>/bin/wso2server.sh
```

Go to line 266 and change as follows

```
-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m \
```

Note that at least having 8GB RAM would be better to run WSO2 API Manager 1.6